# How to make websocket work with traefik and docker?

Tags: docker, websocket, traefik

I've read through all of the related traefik / websocket issues here and other forums, but I wasn't able to solve the problem for my setup.

I'm trying to run Dataiku DSS behind Traefik as reverse proxy. But I'm still new to Traefik and can't figure out how to make websockets for my service work via Traefik.

I'm using the following config:

traefik.yml:

```
api:
  dashboard: true

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false

certificatesResolvers:
  http:
    acme:
      email: admin@example.com
      storage: acme.json
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: http
```

traefik/docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.0
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./data/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - ./data/acme.json:/acme.json
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=<USER>:<PW>"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`traefik.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

dataiku/docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  dataiku:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - dss_data:/home/dataiku/dss
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.dataiku.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.dataiku.rule=Host(`dataiku.example.com`)
      #- traefik.http.middlewares.dataiku-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      #- traefik.http.routers.dataiku.middlewares=dataiku-https-redirect
      #- traefik.http.routers.dataiku-secure.entrypoints=https
      #- traefik.http.routers.dataiku-secure.rule=Host(`dataiku.example.com`)
      #- traefik.http.routers.dataiku-secure.tls=true
      #- traefik.http.routers.dataiku-secure.tls.certresolver=http
      #- traefik.http.routers.dataiku-secure.service=dataiku
      - traefik.http.services.dataiku.loadbalancer.server.port=10000
      - traefik.docker.network=proxy

volumes:
  dss_data:

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

However, when I run dataiku, I see that the websocket connections fail. In Firefox, I see that right after the WS connection is attempted, I get the following error: `XSRF validation failed`.
On Chrome, I see the following: `Error during WebSocket handshake: Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header but no response was received`

The request headers looks like this:

```
Host: example.com
User-Agent: ...
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://example.com
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: dummy, xsrf-7646db48d09813bbe5038c1aa2967e0a9712f81a24b156731f88bde5d3c4d8a5
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 3sSlW9J6GN6d4+bhFr1IIQ==
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
```

The response headers looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Connection: upgrade
Date: Sat, 06 Jun 2020 15:18:08 GMT
Sec-Websocket-Accept: x29WLUMyl5OmRfhZOncdLE65lOU=
Server: nginx
Upgrade: WebSocket
```

Both errors indicate to me, that the response is missing a correct `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` header. But I don't know how to fix that. Initially I thought it might have something to do with TLS, that's why I commented out the secure entrypoint and redirect. But it still exists.

I've previously had no issues with a nginx config like this one:

```
server {
    # Host/port on which to expose Data Science Studio to users
    listen 80;
    server_name dss.example.com;
    location / {
        # Base url of the Data Science Studio installation
        proxy_pass http://DSS_HOST:DSS_PORT/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        # Allow long queries
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        proxy_send_timeout 600;
        # Allow large uploads
        client_max_body_size 0;
        # Allow protocol upgrade to websocket
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?